# How can I make a UDF run only when all info has been entered in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a UDF that has Application.Volatile in it.  This makes entering info very slow.  Is there a way I can run this UDF only when all the info has been entered?  I have tried setting Application.Volatile to false, but then it does not calculate right.

This UDF counts how many cells in a row, have a colored font and displays the number.

Any help would be great.

Amanda

Comment: We are not telepathic. Why don't you [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/836430/edit) your question and share the code in the UDF?

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a **UDF** that operates on a range of values *(say A1 thru A100)* and we do not want to run the **UDF** until all the cells are filled.  Here is one way to accomplish that:

```
=IF(COUNT(A1:A100)<>100,"",MyUDF(A1:A100))
```